# Identify plant stem parts

Tags: botany

[image]

What are the names of the parts A, B, C and D?

This is not homework. I am not a biology specialist. Looked through books for than 30 min. Most of them are schematic diagrams, not photos. Furthermore, the vascular bundle is normally shaped like a cone but this one is crescent shaped.

Comment: Hi hagawaga. I think this is something like your homework. Please, before you post something try to read the terms of posting (homework usually is closed, because this web site is not right for it). Anyway this task can be done in 30 minutes by yourself.

Comment: You said that is not homework, but this is typical question for bio homework. If is not you school duty just tell me for what did you need these think?

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that picture as cauloma. Because it has a trichoms on epidermis. A_ corical parenchyma B_Phloem C_ xylem D_pitch. I hope it will help you.